# Angular Material Datepicker with Moment Adapter: Setting the format of the model value

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, momentjs

I have an Angular Material Datepicker using `momentjs` via the `MomentDateAdapter`. I want to format the value the model receives as `YYYY-MM-DD`. Currently the value in the model is `2019-11-09T05:00:00.000Z`.

I am using a custom date format in form control using `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` to display a verbose date such as `November 9, 2019`. However this does not affect value that the model receives.

This is the code the sets the format for the form control. I don't see any option to set the format for the model value.

```
const VERBOSE_DATE_FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: ['LL', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ],
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
}


@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
      {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
      {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: VERBOSE_DATE_FORMAT},
    ]
})
...
```

I tried using `(dateInput)="onDateChange($event)"`. That exposes `MatDatepickerInput` component via `$event.target`. The `$event.target.value` is a `Moment` object. I tried setting that value with `$event.target.value = $event.target.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` but that did not affect the model.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="date"
        placeholder="Date"
        #date="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="item.date"
        name="date"
        autocomplete="off" 
        (dateInput)="onDateChange($event)"
    >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #date>
    </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


onDateChange( $event ) {
    const formatted = $event.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    $event.target.value = formatted
}
```

I want `item.date` to be `2019-11-09`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hackish, but adding the following to the `<input>` directive produces the desired result:

```
(dateInput)="item.date = $event.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

In full this would look like:

```
<input matInput 
    name="date"
    placeholder="Date"
    #date="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="item.date"
    [matDatepicker]="date"
    (dateInput)="item.date = $event.value.format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
>
```

Answer (score 8):

I just set the `display.dateInput` to whatever I wanted and it worked --

```js
providers: [
        {
            provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
            useValue: {
                display: {
                    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                },
            },
        },
```

Comment: Could you explain where this code belongs?

Comment: It's the `providers` section of your Angular module (e.g. `app.module.ts`)